# Can Facebook detect if I am using their private Graphql API in my Java application?

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

Facebook uses a private Graphql API to power their mobile applications which is not documented publically. Can I use that API in my own application without facebook knowing. If No, then how can Facebook's detection be avoided?

Comment: no, you can only use the official graph api. i hope you are not serious about the rest of your question. if there´s no allowed way, don´t do it. period.

Answer (score 3):

This is a question that no one is likely to answer for sure. IIUC, you want to use an API what has no public documentation, but it is used from their website or application. If they want, they can detect various suspicious patterns:

- Unusual UA string
- Unusual UA fingerprints (TLS ciphersuites, order of HTTP headers, …).
- Unusual activity – the API might be typically used, say, only after loading a user profile. If you use it in some another way, it might be detected. In some cases, you might be suspicious, while in some others, you might be known to use it outside of the official usage.
- Maybe more.

Is it a good idea to use such private API? Not sure. I see two kinds of potential issues:

1. Technical. The API might be removed or modified without a prior notice. This can happen even on purpose if they want you to stop using the API.
2. Legal. I am not a lawyer and don't know all the details (your jurisdiction, Facebook ToS, what API you want to use and how), but I feel this can be potentially a legal issue.

Practically speaking, if you need to use some undocumented API, I suggest at least to think if this usage is aligned with their strategy. You may also ask yourself why there is no public API for that. Maybe they don't want it for some reason (so you can expect them to take some countermeasures, technical or legal). Maybe it is something fast-evolving, so the API is not yet stable enough to be public (so you can expect it to naturally break). Maybe they want to have it, but there is low priority (so you can expect issues rather by accident, but they might still happen).

Comment: 1- I can just copy the UA string from the traffic that I have recorded and post it as it is in my own HTTP request's headers.

Comment: @Marry35 Of course, having a plausible UA is the easiest part. Others are quite harder…

Comment: 2- The API usage behavior tracking does make sense but again, you can always replicate that behavior and Facebook servers will have no idea if that is their own app or something else. Are there any known techniques to monitor API usage behavior that I can study for reference purposes?